# Open network, unable to connect to my devices (two linux laptops and Android smartphone, ), preferably SHH

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, nat-traversal

I will be staying at a hotel with open wifi for some time. My main laptop (Linux Mint 19.3) has a keyboard problem needing replaced as many keys are not working. In the meantime, I would like to connect to my main laptop through SSH with an alternate laptop. The network seems to have client isolation and am hoping for some help with a workaround. Please any suggestions? I have looked into ngrok, ssh forwarding, traversal. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Bring your own router, connect it to the hotel WiFi, and connect each device to your router. GL.iNet and other routers are able to be a WiFi client and AP at the same time. This involves double NAT (your router and then the hotel), but in my experience it works well.

I think the only other way "around" WiFi client isolation is something like a VPN with client-to-client enabled and the server is outside the hotel.

Comment: Thanks again. I will first look into openvpn meanwhile acquiring said router.